# How can I prove this theorem about integrals?

Tags: calculus

be f a integrable function in [a,b], proof that exists c in (a,b) such that
$\int_a^cf(t)dt=\int_c ^bf(t)dt$.

I think that use the Fundamental theorem of calculus can help to proof that.
Whath I did is this:
$\int_a^bf(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$ for FCT

$\int_a^bf(t)dt=\int_a^cf(t)dt+\int_c^bf(t)dt$ for linearity property.

But I don't know how to conclude the proof using that.

Comment: As written, the statement clearly is not true. Take $f(x)=1$, $a=0$, $b=1$.

Comment: If $f$ is positive and continuous on [a,c] and your result is true, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ between $a$ and $c$. This means that the result is not true in general! Check its statement.

Comment: You probably mean $c$ instead of $b$ in the first integral of the equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Assuming that you want a $c$ such that $\int_a^cf=\int_c^b f$)

Define $F(x)=\int_a^x f-\int_x^bf$. Since $f$ is integrable, $F$ is continuous and well-defined.

Note that $F(a)=-\int_a^bf$, $F(b)=\int_a^bf$. It follows from the intermediate value theorem that there must be a $c$ such that $F(c)=0$, which is what you ask for.

Comment: Nicely done!!  +!